# Call JavaScript method on dynamic form element

Tags: javascript

I am creating new textbox using JavaScript. I want to call a JavaScript method onkeyup event of this newly created textbox. How will I do this?

Below is my code:

```
var element2 = document.createElement("input"); 
element2.type = "text"; 
element2.id='complete-field'+tableID;
element2.name=tableID;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) and [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28VS.85%29.aspx) to attach events :

```
if (element2.addEventListener){
  element2.addEventListener('keyup', myFunction, false);
} else if (element2.attachEvent){
  element2.attachEvent('onkeyup', myFunction);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying (http://pastebin.com/m76bb11ec) but it doesn't work in my example.  Can you help me - where I make mistake ?

Comment: @demas : change your "my_f()" line to "function my_f()", then it will work.